# Wicket search form with list view

Tags: forms, listview, search, wicket

Hello everyone I seem to have a problem with my wicket project.

Essentially I have a AjaxLink that when clicked should update the Loadable Detatcheable Model and re render the listview with the results of the updated model

here is my code

```
package com.blackwell.wicket.manager;



public class ManageExercise extends BaseManagerPage {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3241765837700606142L;

private ModalWindow mwAddExercise;

private Integer searchId;
private String name;
private String complexity;
private LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>> modelList;

@SpringBean
ExerciseJdbc exerciseJdbc;

public ManageExercise() {

    add(mwAddExercise = new ModalWindow("mwAddExercise"));

    final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("wmc");
    wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    modelList = exerciseModel(searchId, name, complexity);

    Form<String> searchForm = new Form<String>("searchForm");
    searchForm.add(new TextField<Integer>("searchId",
            new PropertyModel<Integer>(this, "searchId")));
    searchForm.add(new TextField<String>("searchName",
            new PropertyModel<String>(this, "name")));
    // searchForm.add(new DropDownChoice<String>("searchComplexity",
    // new PropertyModel<String>(this, "complexity")));
    searchForm.add(new AjaxLink<String>("searchSubmit") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            modelList = exerciseModel(searchId, name, complexity);
            target.add(wmc);
        }

    });

    add(searchForm);

    ListView<Exercise> lvExercise = new ListView<Exercise>("lvExercise",
            modelList) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Exercise> item) {
            final Exercise model = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("id", Integer.toString(model.getId())));
            item.add(new Label("name", model.getName()));
            item.add(new ExternalLink("demoUrl", model.getDemoUrl(), model
                    .getDemoUrl()));
            item.add(new Label("complexity", model.getComplexity()
                    .getLevel()));
            item.add(new AjaxLink<String>("edit") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    renderAddExercise(item.getModelObject());
                    mwAddExercise.show(target);
                }
            });
            item.add(new AjaxLink<String>("delete") {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    exerciseJdbc.disableExercise(model);
                    target.add(wmc);

                }
            });
        }
    };

    wmc.add(lvExercise);
    add(wmc);

    mwAddExercise.setWindowClosedCallback(new WindowClosedCallback() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(wmc);
        }
    });

    AjaxLink<String> addExercise = new AjaxLink<String>("addExercise") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            renderAddExercise(new Exercise());
            mwAddExercise.show(target);

        }

    };

    add(addExercise);

}

private LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>> exerciseModel(
        final Integer id, final String name, final String complexity) {
    LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>> exercideModel = new LoadableDetachableModel<List<Exercise>>() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        protected List<Exercise> load() {
            return exerciseJdbc.fetchAllExercises(id, name, null,
                    complexity);
        }
    };
    return exercideModel;
}

private void renderAddExercise(Exercise exercise) {
    mwAddExercise.setContent(new AddExercisePanel(mwAddExercise
            .getContentId(), exercise, mwAddExercise));
}

public Integer getSearchId() {
    return searchId;
}

public void setSearchId(Integer id) {
    this.searchId = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getComplexity() {
    return complexity;
}

public void setComplexity(String complexity) {
    this.complexity = complexity;
}
```

}

Now the problem is upon clicking the link this is not happening.

I have verfied that the method that is run in the load() method returns what i would expect when the correct arguments are passed through.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you do that:

```
modelList = exerciseModel(searchId, name, complexity);
```

You are creating a new instance of your `LoadableDetachableModel`, so your `ListView` still have the previous one.

In Wicket you must update the objects of the model, no the model itself.

Comment: ok might you be able to tell me what the accepted way of going about this is ?

Comment: modelList.setObject( ... )

Answer (score 0):

Use also propertymodels in populateItem

new Label("complexity", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "complexity.level"))

Detach modelList as well (onDetach())